# Sequelize joining two tables which are not associated

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I am trying to retrieve data by joining two tables which are not "associated" using a relationship.  These two tables are as below:

```
mysql> desc partner_txns;
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| txn_id     | int(11)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| user_id    | int(11)     | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| txn_type   | varchar(1)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| txn_amnt   | double      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| desc       | varchar(64) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| createdBy  | int(11)     | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| created_on | datetime    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> desc accounts_master;
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name        | varchar(64) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| owner       | int(11)     | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| type        | int(11)     | YES  |     | 0       |                |
| expires_on  | datetime    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| max_lists   | int(11)     | YES  |     | 10      |                |
| max_groups  | int(11)     | YES  |     | 10      |                |
| createdBy   | int(11)     | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| modifiedBy  | int(11)     | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| created_on  | datetime    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| modified_on | datetime    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
11 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Without using sequelize, normally I would make an SQL query like this:

```
mysql> select a.user_id, b.name from partner_txns a, accounts_master b where a.createdBy = 3 and a.user_id = b.owner;
+---------+-------------+
| user_id | name        |
+---------+-------------+
|       8 | New account |
|       8 | Comviva     |
|       8 | Infosys     |
|       9 | HDFC        |
|       9 | INTEGRA     |
+---------+-------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

What is the equivalent of doing this using Sequelize, assuming I have these two tables as two models as below:

- PartnerTxn
- Account

I am tempted to use like:

```
var Model = require('ecp_model');

Model.PartnerTxn.findAll({
  where: {createdBy:3 },
  include : [{model:Model.Account, attribute:['name']}]
}).then(function(results) {
   console.log("results:", results);
});
[rv.nath@localhost authserver]$
```

But then this won't work because these two tables are not related.  So, I get an error as below:

```
Unhandled rejection Error: Account is not associated to PartnerTxn!
    at validateIncludedElement (/var/opt/ecp_db/node_modules/sequelize/lib/model.js:569:11)
    at /var/opt/ecp_db/node_modules/sequelize/lib/model.js:452:29
    at Array.map (native)
    at validateIncludedElements (/var/opt/ecp_db/node_modules/sequelize/lib/model.js:448:37)
    at null.<anonymous> (/var/opt/ecp_db/node_modules/sequelize/lib/model.js:1360:32)
    at tryCatcher (/var/opt/ecp_db/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
    at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/var/opt/ecp_db/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:503:31)
    at Promise._settlePromise (/var/opt/ecp_db/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:560:18)
    at Promise._settlePromise0 (/var/opt/ecp_db/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:605:10)
    at Promise._settlePromises (/var/opt/ecp_db/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:684:18)
    at Async._drainQueue (/var/opt/ecp_db/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:126:16)
    at Async._drainQueues (/var/opt/ecp_db/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:136:10)
    at Immediate.Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate] (/var/opt/ecp_db/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:16:14)
    at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:383:17)
```

Comment: Why don't you associate them?

Comment: user_id field of partner_txns is linked to id in another table (users_master).  Similarly the owner field of accounts_master is linked to id in (users_master).  Which means there is a 3rd table "users_master", so these two tables in qn are not linked to each other directly.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is almost a year afterward, but in case anyone is in your situation and looking for the correct answer.

When you have two separate data types linked by a third table, you are looking for Sequelize's BelongToMany(Through).

So in your case, you would need to define a third Model: UserMaster. You would give UserMaster two attributes: user_id (same as the PartnerTxn attribute) and owner (same as the Account attribute).

Then you would do this:

```
Account.belongsToMany(PartnerTxn, {through: 'UserMaster'});
PartnerTxn.belongsToMany(Account, {through: 'UserMaster'});
```

For further reference, the [documentation](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/2.0/docs/associations/#belongs-to-many-associations) has information.

Comment: What if the two tables are not logically associated, but you just want to get the result on a single query? As far as the question goes, there is no indication that the two tables should be associated via a third table, and I don't find it a good idea to add a third table just for the sake of getting the results in a single sequelize query.

Comment: does anyone have an answer for it? I have tried to do it with a simple join instead of an include and it doesn't work. Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

```
const items = await MainModel.findAll({
  include: [{
    model: MyOtherModel,
    on: sequelize.literal('"MainModel"."pk_column" = "MyOtherModel"."fk_column"::text');
  }]
});
```

You can as well cast the column type if the datatypes are different