# Formatting return Type of the column in Sequelize

Tags: sql-server, node.js, sequelize.js

I have used Sequelize to state the type of one of my columns as follows:

```
userTime: DataTypes.TIME
```

This declares the column in MS SQL as `time(7)` format.
I add data to the respective column as a string. e.g: "12:00"
However, when I retrieve the data from the DB it comes out in the following format:

```
userTime: "1970-01-01T12:00:00.000Z"
```

How can I change the output to be of the following format, using Sequelize:
userTime: "12:00"

Is there a possibility, to use FORMAT of the return type in Sequelize?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I would suggest is to create a `getterMethods` , work like a `virtual field` , that you will get in each query.

```
var User = sequelize.define('users',{
    userTime:{
        type: DataTypes.TIME    
    },
    name:{
        type: db.Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
    image: {
        type: db.Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: true
    },
    .... // other fields
},{
    getterMethods:{
        modifiedUserTime() {
            return moment(this.userTime); // modify the time as you want
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I solved the problem, was way easier than I thought.

```
userTime: {
    type: DataTypes.TIME,
    allowNull: true,
    get() {
      const userTime = this.getDataValue('userTime');
      if(userTime == null) return  userTime;
      const time = new Date(userTime);
      let hours = addZero(time.getUTCHours());
      let minutes = addZero(time.getUTCMinutes());
      let combinedTime = hours + ":" + minutes;
      return combinedTime;
    }
}   
function addZero(i) {
if (i < 10) {
    i = "0" + i;
}
return i;
}
```

Comment: This will return original field modified , I would suggest to go with mine solution , as it keep field as it is and return another with expected value.

Comment: I know, its not the correct place to ask it, but can you help me with this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47215961/sequelize-js-join-tables-without-associations    
I tried looking for this in documentation, but could not find any solution.

Comment: I long as i know you must provide the association for that , or else you have to make raw query by your self. There is no other way.