Reference main column from subquery Sequelize
Customers is the table name, but i am getting

Unknown column 'customers.id' in 'where clause'

I have tried every possible solution, even directly from the documentation.
const customers = await this.repository.findAndCountAll({
    where: condition,
    attributes: {
        // exclude: ['user_id', 'account_id', 'deletedAt'],
        include: [
            [
                Sequelize.literal(`(
                    SELECT SUM(amount)
                    FROM transactions
                    WHERE transactions.customer_id = customers.id
                    and transaction_type='PAYOUT'
                )`), 'totalDebit'
            ]
        ]
    },
    limit,
    offset,
    include: {
        association: 'groups',
        where: { id: groupId },
        through: { attributes: [] },
        attributes:[],
        required: true
    },
    order:[['createdAt', 'DESC']],
    raw: true,
});

return customers


Shouldn't "customers" be in your from clause? There is no subquery even here. Although, I know nothing about sequalize, but your syntax seems wrong.

I”m trying to fetch a transaction of a customer while retrieving the customer , this particular query using sub query is directly from the sequelize documentation, but I have no idea why it is complaining of the column . Can you share the correct syntax instead ?

Doesn't seem to be as simple as I though, but I think this is about the same issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47215961/sequelize-js-join-tables-without-associations

Thank you for sharing the reference James. But I have checked and our goal is different, he is trying to include a model that doesn’t have any association but I am trying to run a sub query to add extra properties to the current query, the only issue is the sub query not being able to refer to the main query column .

I was able to resolve this , turns out i needed to use the alias sequelize had generated for the customers , i had to log the query and see the raw sql, then use the alias instead of the table name. Incase anyone face this issue in the future
 const customers = await this.repository.findAndCountAll({
            where: condition,
            attributes: {
                // exclude: ['user_id', 'account_id', 'deletedAt'],
                include: [
                    [
                        Sequelize.literal(`(
                            SELECT SUM(amount)
                            FROM transactions
                            WHERE transactions.customer_id = CustomerModel.id
                            and transaction_type='PAYOUT'
                        )`), 'totalDebit'
                    ]
                ]
            },
            limit,
            offset,
            include: {
                association: 'groups',
                where: { id: groupId },
                through: { attributes: [] },
                attributes:[],
                required: true
            },
            order:[['createdAt', 'DESC']],
            raw: true,
            logging: console.log,
        });

